# Jaws Form Field View Tabbing Fields

Tags: forms, jaws-screen-reader

Since starting Jaws 2018, after viewing my form using insert + F5, some of the fields are somehow indented and not being read by JAWS.  My screenshot will show in more detail. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDo1j.png)

Comment: I am having a similar thing.  AND our developers are using Unicode/html/wingdings to indicate Envelope/Phone, so the first character of many elements are "phone icon" or "envelope icon", so users can't hit the normal "first character" to find the items beginning with, say, "T".